# Map network drives group policy logon script VBSCRIPT

Tags: windows, vbscript, server, gpo

Im using this code:

```
WScript.Sleep(6000)
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "W:" , "\\server\D"
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "X:" , "\\server\E"
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "Y:" , "\\server\F"
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "Z:" , "\\server\G"

MsgBox "!!!!!!!"
```

It works perfectly fine when i double click this script. It'll map the network drives.

Whenever i set this up as a group policy logon script, the script WILL run (because the messagebox appears at computer login), but the drives are not mapped. What am i missing here?

The server uses: Windows Server 2012 R2
and the client uses: Windows 10 PRO

Comment: If you are an admin then they are run as a limited user and drive mapping are to the logon token. Admins have two - limited and elevated. Are your drives available when you are unelevated.

Comment: Why not just use a batch file, all you are doing is mapping some drives? VBScripts will always have issues running especially when UAC is enabled on the clients.

Comment: @bgalea I don't know what you mean exactly. I am administrator on the client PC, but also have all administrator rights in the domain.

Comment: @lankymart UAC is disabled on the client. Maybe ill try a bat file.

Comment: @Lankymart With a batch file, its the same story, the drives do not appear at "My PC". 
When i type "net use" in the command prompt, i see the drives connected over there, they all have the status "OK"

Comment: The suggestion to use a batch file is purely from a compatibility point of view across clients, you will always get more issues running a VBScript then using a batch file. In this instance though just sounds like a permission issue. What error do you get when attempting to map them?

Comment: @Lankymart I know what the problem is now. When i run CMD as administrator and type in "net use" i see the drives there. (i can also access them in CMD, and see all the folders and stuff)

When i run CMD as normal user and type in "net use" i DO NOT see the drives there. Somehow the batch file is running as administrator, therefore the drives are not showing up in file explorer.

The question remains, how do i fix this?

Comment: Can a normal (non-privileged) user manually browse to that server share and map it?  Just type the path in the Run box to check it.

Comment: @lars, if you run a logon script for the user, do you get a list from this:  `dir \\server\g\*.* > c:\temp.txt` ?  Are they able to list the drive at logon?

Comment: @RLH yep.. i made a bat file with "dir \\server\g\*.* > c:\temp.txt" and set it as logon script. It made a txt file with text in it(like volume serial number is.. etc)

That works fine because the bat file gets ran as administrator.. (normally you can't save directly to C:\ because you need administrator rights to do so...

It also works when i ran the logon script(with the mapping drives) and just entered "dir \\server\g\*.* > c:\temp.txt" manually in the CMD.. (not on the C:\ drive though) because i get access denied (need administrator rights)

Comment: @Lars,  you need to add error handling and see what error is being thrown by the method.  Info here on error handling. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692852.aspx

Comment: @RLH I don't get any errors.. the problem is that the bat script gets executed as administrator.. thats why i dont see any drives in file explorer. If i manually add the drives (net use etc, as administrator, i don't see the drives either...)